# Get response from url using ajax and jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

want to get response from url using ajax and jquery.

tried with this code

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
     $.ajax({ 
       type: 'POST', 
       url: 'apexweb.co.in/apex_quote/uname_validation.asp?,
       dataType:'jsonp', 
      success: function(data){ 
           alert(data); 
      } 
    });
});
```

i want to display response as fail but i didn't get any response on browser

Help Me

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://www.apexweb.co.in/apex_quote/uname_validation.asp?,
                dataType:'jsonp',
                
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
i used this code

Comment: modify your question with your code

Comment: And what doesn't work about it? Do you get an error?

Comment: i am not getting any response. I am new to ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "apexweb.co.in/apex_quote/uname_validation.asp?",                
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d); 
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: is your url is correct i.e. "apexweb.co.in/apex_quote/uname_validation.asp?"

Comment: This is my url http://www.apexweb.co.in/apex_quote/uname_validation.asp?. click on that u will get response as fail

Comment: The url must contain a function which will return a value or return the object based on the requirement. Try to make a function at uname_validation.asp and append it in the url..

Comment: I am new to this subject. can u show me the example. Thanx in advance

Comment: You can find more over here
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp and 

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @  nrsharma where to call uname_validation.asp